# How to listen to a property update state o android

Tags: android, kotlin

My application uses WebView with JavaScript lib and I enabled the  `addJavascriptInterface` so I could use the modal to access or send information to the JavaScript file, the problem is, I can't have control over the information that it was requested, there's no callback to ensure that it was called, so there is anything that I can "attach" to any property and listen if the state changed and then make the logic ? The way I'm doing is waiting 4 seconds to ensure that, the request was made, but not efficient.

```
 webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/installments.html")

        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                val type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<Installments>>() {}.type
                var response: MutableList<Installments>? = Gson().fromJson(pay.installments!!, type)
                if (response != null) {
                    for (i in 0 until response.size){
                        installments.add(response[i].recommended_message)
                    }

                    val adapterInstallments = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        installments)

                    activity!!.runOnUiThread {
                        spinner.adapter = adapterInstallments
                        adapterInstallments.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }

                }
            }
        }, 4000)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know when the `webview` finishes loading its content.

Instead of forcing it to wait 4 seconds, as loading could take more than 4 seconds(ex. bad internet connection), you could add a `listener` to a `webview` to detect when it finishes loading.

Try the sample code below:

```
webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        // called after webview finished loading
        // place here the logic to call after webview loads
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Not just load, but the JavaScript call. Loading the page is one thing but knowing exactly whenever the request from the Lib was returned, that's the problem .